How to Display a Modal on Click Event of a Polygon in a Django Class-Based View Using Folium Map?
I'm using Folium in a Django CBV to display a map with polygons. How can I trigger a modal to appear with more region details when a user clicks on a polygon?
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}

    # Retrieve form and queryset data
    context['RegionalMalnutritionForm'] = RegionalMalnutritionForm()

    context['regional_levels'] = RegionalLevel.objects.all()  
    context['national_levels'] = NationalLevel.objects.filter(age_category=1, year_record=1)

     #for Default map when open the pages - Regional is the default for malutrition module
    min_id = YearCategoryMalnutrition.objects.all().order_by('id').first().id
    age_category_min_id = AgeCategory.objects.all().order_by('id').first().id
    coodinate_locations =    RegionalLevel.objects.filter(year_record=min_id,age_category=age_category_min_id)

    geo_data = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}

    for location in coodinate_locations:
        json_string = location.regional_level_coordinate.region_coordinate
        polygons_type = location.regional_level_coordinate.geo_type
        malnutrition_category = location.malnutrition_category
        percentage = location.percentage
        age_category = location.age_category
        color = location.color.hex_color
        region_name = location.region_name
        
        geo_data['features'].append(self.create_geojson_feature(json.loads(json_string,), polygons_type, 
        percentage,age_category,malnutrition_category,color,region_name))

    folium_map = self.create_map()

     

    # Add the feature to the map with the popup
    folium.GeoJson(
        geo_data,
        highlight_function=highlight_function, 
        style_function=style_function,
        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
            fields=['Data'], 
            aliases=[''],
            localize=True,
            style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); color: white; font-size: 16px; padding:8px;",
        ),
    ).add_to(folium_map)

    
 


    # Convert map to HTML representation
    context['folium_map'] = folium_map._repr_html_()

I tried adding an onclick event to the polygons in my Folium map within a Django class-based view, expecting a modal to be triggered on click. The modal should display detailed information about the clicked region. However, this doesn't work as expected and the click event does not trigger the modal.
